# closed substack of quotient stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, group-actions, algebraic-stacks, universal-property

The question concerns quotient stacks. I am not very comfortable with stacks, so feel free to edit the question if I am saying nonsense. It is also the reason why I may be spelling in too much detail some obvious facts...

Fix a base scheme $S$ for everything that follows. Say we have a quotient stack $[X/G]$, where $X$ is a scheme and $G$ acts on $X$ (e.g. $G=GL_n$) and consider $F$ a substack of $[X/G]$, such that $F\hookrightarrow [X/G]$ is representable **and a closed immersion.**

(If it helps, think of $[X/G]$ as some moduli space of some objects and $F$ a moduli space classifying those objects with an extra property $P$).

If I understand correctly, we have a map (of stacks) $X\to[X/G]$ corresponding to the trivial torsor $G\times X$:
\begin{array}{c c c}
G\times X & \to & X \\
\downarrow & & \\
X &  & 
\end{array}
where the vertical map is projection and the horizontal is the action.

**Q1**: *is this map universal in any sense?* (It seems so to me, but I can't make it a precise statement). In the moduli space setting, it seems to correspond to ''the most general object'' you can write, assuming the objects can be cut out by equations). *Does this make sense?*

**Edit/addendum to Q1:** *In the moduli space setting, the "distinguished" element $X\to[X/G]$ corresponds to some object $A$ over $X$. What can be said about $A$?*

Continuing, take the fiber product
\begin{array}{c c c}
Z & \to & F \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
X & \to & [X/G]
\end{array}
gives a closed subscheme $Z$ of $X$ (by the assumption on $F$).

**Q2**: *Under what conditions on $F$ (or is it always true), do we have $F=[Z/G]$?* A priori, it's not even clear that $Z$ has a $G$-action, but I believe I checked that and I think I can write a map $[Z/G]\to F$.

And the last question:
**Q3**: Again, *is there any "universality" to this?* It seems to me that it says something along the lines of: take a scheme $U$ over $S$. Then a map $U\to[X/G]$ corresponds to an object $A$ classified by our moduli problem and the assumption on $F$ shows that the fiber product $V$ is closed in $U$:
\begin{array}{c c c}
V & \to & F \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
U & \to & [X/G]
\end{array}
Then $A$ (over $U$) has property $P$ if and only if it factors through $V$? Or maybe (if $P$ can be checked on points), $V$ is the ''locus'' where the object $A$ has property $P$. *Does this make sense?*

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that the map $X\to [X/G]$ satisfies a universal property the category of stacks (without explicitly referring to $X$). For example, you can write a $pt = [G/G]$ for any group $G$... more generally, a given stack may be expressed as a quotient stack in multiple ways, so $X$ is not uniquely determined.

Comment: I believe the answer to Q2 is "always": $Z\to F$ is the pullback of the $G$-torsor $X\to [X/G]$, so in particular is a $G$-torsor itself.

Comment: Here's a silly remark. Consider the circle $Y = S^1$. Let $X_1 = R^2 - 0$, so that $Y = X_1/G = [X_1/G]$, where $G = R - 0$ (as the action is free, the brackets [ ] don't do anything). On the other hand, let $X_2 = R$. We could view $Y = X_2/Z$. The only thing intrinsic about Y is Y itself, and $X_1, X_2$ are giving you two presentations of $Y$ as a quotient. I think this is partly why Q1 and Q3 lack a good answer. On the other hand, the answer to Q2 is 'always true', as SG said. That's bcause the pullback of a G-bundle is a G-bundle, and the map $X \to [X/G]$ is a G-bundle (aka torsor).

Comment: Thanks @SamGunningham and Yosemite Sam (can't tag both for some reason). What if in Q1 and Q3 we restrict to the category of $X$-schemes? (and hence objects to be classified over schemes over $X$). Also, any thoughts on the last part of Q3 (about objects having property $P$)? (it doesn't depend on a specific choice of $X$..)

Comment: I modified Q1 a bit. I think it's less vague now.